# Lua math.random explain

Tags: lua, love2d

sorry for asking this question but I couldn't understand it

```
-- but i don't understand this code
ballDX = math.random(2) == 1 and 100 or -100
--here ballDY will give value between -50 to 50 
ballDY = math.random(-50, 50)
```

I don't understand the structure what is (2) and why it's == 1

Thank you a lot

Comment: Another common way to do a 50-50 chance is to use `math.random() < 0.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`math.random(x)`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-math.random) will randomly return an integer between 1 and x.

So `math.random(2)` will randomly return 1 or 2.

If it returns 1 (`== 1`), `ballDX` will be set to 100.

If it returns 2 (`~= 1`), `ballDX` will be set to -100.

A simple way to make a 50-50 chance.

Answer (score 1):

In lua

```
result = condition and first or second
```

basically means the same as

```
if condition and first ~= nil and first ~= false then
    result = first
else
    result = second
end
```

So in your case

```
if math.random(2) == 1 then
    ballDX = 100
else
    ballDX = -100
end
```

in other words, there is a 50/50 chance for ballDX to become 100 or -100

Comment: Only correct if `first` is truthy.

Comment: @LMD you're right, didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

That is a very common way of assigning variables in Lua based on conditionals. It’s the same you’d do, for example, in Python with “foo = a if x else b”:
The first function, math.random(2), returns either 1 or 2. So, if it returns 1 the part math.random(2) == 1 is true and so you assign 100 to the variable ballDX. Otherwise, assign -100 to it.

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding, a look at lua documentation helps a lot :
https://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html

You can read:
*The operator or returns its first argument if it is not false; otherwise, it returns its second argument:*

So if the random number is 1 it will return the first argument (100) of the "or" otherwise it will return the second argument (-100).